# sorting products based on price range woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

guys. I was wondering how I'd be able to sort my products based on a certain pricerange. As an example we could say I wanted to have these options places on my frontpage:

< $400 | $400 - $800 | $800 - $1200

It should work like that when I click on one of these three buttons, I'd see the products in the chosen pricerange.

Did anybody make something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `meta_query` from [WP_Query](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/). you will find product properties in `postmeta`.

For related price meta_key(s) you have `_regular_price`, `_sale_price`, `_price`

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => '_regular_price',
        'value' => array( 400,800 ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
),
```